# QUICK & EASY : Python Selenium, How do I grab this text using xpath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

The desired output is to print: "Kallie" using the xpath. I cannot share the link to the website because it requires a password.

Here is a screenshot of the elements.
[image]

When I right click the highlighted line > Copy > Copy Full Xpath, I get:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/article/a/span[1]/h5
```

The following are my attempts based on other questions asked on Stack Overflow.

Attempt 1:

```
word = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/article/a/span[1]/h5')
print(word)

#PRINTS <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="33b2fc3b827f954e5cb48bf50ce96567", element="D0BA6376742ACE33E80B5BB2696E9A74_element_154")>
```

Attempt 2:

```
word = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/article/a/span[1]/h5').text
print(word)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Attempt 3:

```
word = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/article/a').text
print(word)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Attempt 4:

```
word = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/article/a/span[1]//h5').text
print(word)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Attempt 5:

```
word = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//html//body//div[2]//div[1]//div//div[3]//div//div[1]//article//a//span[1]//h5').text
print(word)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Attempt 6:

```
word = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h5').text
print(word)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Attempt 7:

```
word = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h5").text
print(word)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Attempt 8:

```
for a in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "h5"):
    print(a.text)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Attempt 9:

```
for a in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "//h5"):
    print(a.text)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Please help thx love u.

Comment: You seem to have slapped every tag containing the word Selenium making it hard to figure out what you are looking for. I'm assuming this has nothing to do with [selenium-grid] since it's not mentioned. I'm guessing that it has nothing to do with [selenium-ide] because it's not specifically mentioned either.  You don't show your browser instantiation code so we don't know if you are using Chromedriver but I can pretty much guarantee you that this has nothing to do with specifically the Chrome browser. You should remove those 3 tags and then add [python] since that's the language you're using.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt 1 is printing class info and a GUID because you are printing the WebElement and not the contained text. You are headed down the right path in #2 by accessing `.text` but that and all the later attempts are printing BLANK because the page isn't fully loaded. You need to add a `WebDriverWait` to ensure the element is visible before accessing the `.text`. The other major issue is that you are using an absolute XPath, one that starts from `/html`, which is very brittle. This means that even minor updates to the page are more likely to break your locators.

Without access to the actual page, it's going to be really hard to give you a really good locator. One that should work is the CSS selector,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
e = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ascene_1626113 h5'))).text
print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the code below, unfortunately it printed blank. driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ascene_1626113 h5").text

Comment: Did you add the `WebDriverWait` I mentioned as well? That's going to be required to print anything other than blank. I've updated my answer with all the required code.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. I copy pasted your code exactly, this time I got an error.     raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException. Any suggestions?

Comment: That means that the ID is dynamic. If you want help, you need to remove the screenshot of the HTML and replace it with the text of the HTML as I commented already. We need more info from surrounding elements to create a new locator that will work consistently.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried these?

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@text, 'kallie')]")

Or

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='kallie']")

Comment: The first one won't work because you don't have the capitalization correct. Also, there could be more than one element that contains that text so your locator potentially won't get the right one even after correcting it. The second one won't work because that element clearly contains more text than just 'kallie'.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should have specified that you cannot use the word that you are trying to print within the solution.

Comment: Ah, ok sorry. I was working on something similar but searching for link text. Good luck.

Comment: @zackchess3 `I should have specified that you cannot use the word that you are trying to print within the solution.`
You should update your question with this info.